# Is there a way to use different operators/statements in a WHEN clause after WHERE

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm trying to create a WHERE clause that, when no argument has been given, will just return all the files (thus filename = filename) else the Filename has to be LIKE the argument passed.

I tried using a few solutions, the 2 below (the one in comment and the on beneath that) seem the most promising but can't seem to get them to work.

using `"AND Filename = (CASE WHEN @name IS NULL THEN FileName ELSE(@name IS NULL AND FileName = FileName) OR ( FileName LIKE '@name' )"` doesn't work because I need to set Filename to something (with =)  but if the argument has been passed it needs to be a LIKE instead of a '=' and I didn't seem to find a way to use a different operator.

Is there a way to solve this issue?

```
SELECT Application, CreationDate, Filename
FROM AXSENTINEL.AXSENTINEL.current_664943629
WHERE ISArchived IS NULL
AND Application = 'UL3_ACTO_3MNDWAARDEOVERZIC'
AND CreationDate >= Dateadd(MONTH,-3,getdate())
--AND (@name IS NULL AND Filename = Filename) OR (@name IS NOT NULL AND FileName LIKE '%@name%')
AND Filename = (CASE WHEN @name IS NULL 
                   THEN FileName 
                   ELSE(@name IS NULL AND FileName = FileName) 
OR ( FileName LIKE '@name' )
```

Essentially I just want to build some kind of IF code in my WHERE clause:

```
IF @name IS NULL
    THEN Filename = Filename
    ELSE Filename LIKE '%@name%'
FI
```

Comment: `where (Filename = @name or @name is null)`?

Comment: You could use `FileName like Coalesce( @Name, '%' )` or `FileName like Coalesce( '%' + @Name + '%', '%' )` depending on whether you want to add wildcards to the pattern or not. You may be heading in the direction of [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html).

Answer (score 0):

(Extending on jarlh's comment) If you need LIKE rather than exact match:

```
where (Filename LIKE '%' + @name + '%' or @name is null)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
where filename like '%' + coalesce(@name, '') + '%'
```